# Can't figure how to run bouncy ball sample agdk android OpenGL

Tags: android, c++, sdk, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am trying to integrate the frame pacing library into my opengl code.
I am simply trying to follow the instructions here to open the sample so that I can run it: https://developer.android.com/games/sdk/frame-pacing/opengl

I cloned the repository with git as they said using

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/gamesdk
```

If I understand correctly, all I have to do is make sure that I have the ndk and sdk installed? I remember installing all the available versions using the tool menu.

In the google link above they say that all I have to do is to "Click File > Open and select the gamesdk/samples/bouncyball directory." but that doesn't work.

When I try to compile and run it I get this error: 'Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':wrapper' (type 'Wrapper').

- In plugin 'org.gradle.build-init' type 'org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper' property 'jarFile' is not writable because 'C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\gamesdk\samples\bouncyball\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar' ancestor 'C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\gamesdk\samples\bouncyball\gradle' is not a directory.'

and it looks like this in my ide:
[image]

I am probably missing something?

If anyone can help me building this bouncy ball sample thank you infinitely !

Comment: I recommend you improve your contrast and font height before posting pictures.

Comment: Indeed I have a pretty high res screen, will certainly do that thanks
fixed

Comment: Have you tried creating the directory it's complaining about?

Comment: At C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\gamesdk\samples\bouncyball\.gradle I can find 4 files, so I think that the directory already exists. Is that what you meant? 
I noticed a dot before .gradle so I tried to create a folder called gradle without the . prefix but windows says 'there is already a file with the same name'